# MyBatis/Spring - Transactional method

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I have a problem with my `@Transactional` method. After this method executed - the new record inserted into table and no rollback happens on exception

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestMapper testMapper;

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    String test() {
        TestObj obj = new TestObj();
        obj.setName(new Date().toString());
        testMapper.insert(obj);

        int i = 1 / 0; // doing exception

        return obj.toString();
    }
}
```

My xml configurations:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/test"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.test.mapper"/>
</bean>
```

Am i missing something? I just want DB to stay unchanged if some exception happens in my method

**EDIT:**
The problem was that method was not defined as `public`

Answer (score 0):

Just throw new RuntimeException and change your annotation to `@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)`.

Comment: changed my line, that throws exception to `if (true) { throw new RuntimeException(); }` and added `rollbackFor = Exception.class` but this not helped... still the records inserted into table

Answer (score 0):

We had this kind of problem, here is the conf we use it may help you. Note that we are relying on the ApplicationServer:

```
<!-- Initialize MyBatis Session Factory -->
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <!-- Plug datasource and mapperLocations -->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionFactory">
        <bean
            class="org.apache.ibatis.transaction.managed.ManagedTransactionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```